# Django Rest Framework - timezone for datetime field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using DRF > 3.0; I want to control the serialization of a DateTime field in my model. Specifically, I want the date-time to be output in **ANY** timezone (not just in settings.TIME_ZONE; which is the default).
The timezone i want to use is received as a keyword argument when i create an instance of my serializer. However I get an `AttributeError` when i try to set the timezone on the `MySerializer.deployment_time.timezone = self.timezone` code line.

How can I set the "timezone" attribute on the "deployment_time" instance. Or is there another way of achieving this?

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    deployment_time = serializers.DateTimeField(format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'])

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.timezone = kwargs.pop('timezone') if 'timezone' in kwargs else None
        super(MySerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.timezone:
            MySerializer.deployment_time.timezone = self.timezone
```

> AttributeError: type object 'MySerializer' has no attribute
>   'deployment_time'

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to replace the error line with

self.deployment_time.timezone = self.timezone